# How to get array value from wordpress database get_results

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

Trying to echo the array value from my mysql query (inside Wordpress snippet)

```
function get_customer_gain() {
  global $wpdb; 
  $users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SUM(wp_wpdatatable_1.payback) FROM wp_wpdatatable_1");
  foreach( $users as $user ) {
    echo $user;
  }
}
add_shortcode('customer_gain', 'get_customer_gain');
```

my var_dump is:
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3098 (1) { ["SUM(wp_wpdatatable_1.payback)"]=> string(6) "183320" } }

So basically im trying to echo that 183320 number

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: just use `$number = $wpdb->get_var(SELECT SUM(..."`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the correct syntax `$wpdb->get_results( $query, $type_of_result);`

check this out [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/)

**EDIT FOR EXPLAINATION:**

```
$users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SUM(wp_wpdatatable_1.payback) as sumed FROM wp_wpdatatable_1", ARRAY_A);
```

The `array_a` will retur associative array while by default it returns as object that cause problem

Comment: accepted param : ARRAY_A || ARRAY_N || OBJECT || OBJECT_K

Comment: once the output is done by ARRAY_A you can access the value

Comment: This is the better solution if already know there is only one row.

Answer (score 3):

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow

Your code must change to

```
function get_customer_gain() {
  global $wpdb; 
  $users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SUM(wp_wpdatatable_1.payback) as sumed FROM wp_wpdatatable_1");
  foreach( $users as $user ) {
    echo $user->sumed;
  }
}
add_shortcode('customer_gain', 'get_customer_gain');
```

Comment: if I could ask another question... if i use the same code to get a value from another column...  then i want to get the difference between those two?  from the example above (SELECT SUM(wp_wpdatatable_1.payback...   then SELECT SUM(wp_wpdatatable_1.car ...